# How to show a form again after hiding it?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, minimize, maximize-window

I have two forms. I need to open a second form with a button. When I open form2 I hide form1. However when I try to show form1 again from form2 with a button it doesn't work. My form1 code is:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();        
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Inside form2 code:

```
Form1.ActiveForm.ShowDialog();
```

or

```
Form1.ActiveForm.Show();
```

or

```
form1.show(); (form1 doesn't exist in the current context)
```

doesn't work.
I do not want to open a new form

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();   
form1.ShowDialog();
```

I want show the form which I hided before. 
Alternatively I can minimize it to taskbar

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

and maximize it from form2 again.

```
Form2.ActiveForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

however the way I am trying is again doesn't work.
What is wrong with these ways?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try (on Form1 button click)

```
Hide();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();        
form2.ShowDialog();
form2 = null;
Show();
```

or (it should work)

```
Hide();
using (Form2 form2 = new Form2())       
    form2.ShowDialog();
Show();
```

Comment: thank you very much. adding hide(); show(); solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Preserve the instance of `Form1` and use it to `Show` or `Hide`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access Form1 from Form2 throught the Owner property if you show form2 like this:

```
form2.ShowDialog( form1 )
```

or like this:

```
 form2.Show( form1 )
```

Notice this way you are not forced to use ShowDialog cause hide and show logic can be moved inside Form2

Answer (score 1):

This method is the one that I find works the best for me

Primary Form

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
```

Secondary Form

```
private Form Form1
public Form2(Form Form1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Form1 = Form1;
    Form1.Hide();
}
```

Later on when closing

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      FormCollection frm = Application.OpenForms;

        foreach(Form f in frm)
        {
            if(f.Name=="yourformname")
            {
                f.Show();
                this.Close();                    
                this.Dispose();
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).